# How do I export the CodeSnippets on Xcode10?

Tags: xcode10

- Firstly, I want to export the CodeSnippets to my other computer.
- Secondly, I tried to copy the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/userData/CodeSnippets` directory to my other computer under the same directory,but it doesn't work.
- Lastly, I used xcode10 to create a Code Snippet on my other computer, and go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/userData`，but I didn't found `CodeSnippets` directory.
- So,I don‘t how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

> - Lastly, I used xcode10 to create a Code Snippet on my other computer, and go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/userData`，but I didn't found CodeSnippets directory.
>
> **The reason why you weren't able to locate CodeSnippets directory on your other computer might be due to the directory been hidden.**

**Import/Export Custom Snippets**

We can find our custom code snippets at the path `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/`.

**Since Library is a hidden folder**, we can either open this path with the terminal command:

```
open `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/`
```

Or you can let the Finder shows the hidden files with the terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true && killall Finder
```

If you want to hide again the hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles false && killall Finder
```

Every time we add/remove files in this folder, **we must restart Xcode**.

Comment: Clean install Xcode 14 does not make /CodeSnippets folder by default. I had to manually create it and copied old snippets in.